# PyPy: can't monkeypatch ast classes?

Tags: python, data-structures, monkeypatching, pypy

This line of code fails in PyPy:

```
expr.__repr__ = lambda self: ast.dump(self, annotate_fields=False)
TypeError: can't set attributes on type object 'expr'
```

even though it works great in normal python, i.e. it gives my AST nodes a sensible `__repr__`. Is there any reason why it doesn't work in PyPy, and is there any way to work around it? My attempts to monkey-patch the `repr` function itself have met with failure.

Comment: http://clarete.github.io/forbiddenfruit/   ... might work ... although it might not work for repr ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley From that page: "Since Forbidden Fruit is fundamentally dependent on the C API, this library won't work on other python implementations, such as Jython, PyPy, etc."

Comment: oh your right ... sorry ...missed that :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way. On PyPy, AST classes act like builtin types like `list` or `int` in that you can't alter them. If you want to define a custom repr, about the best you can do is define your own function. You may find the `ast.NodeVisitor` class handy for implementing such a function.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I tested forbiddenfruit to add a method to int on cpython 3.6.6 and it worked:

```
$ipython
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jul 21 2018, 02:39:08)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from forbiddenfruit import curse

In [2]: curse(int, 'test', lambda self: 'hi')

In [3]: (1).test()
Out[3]: 'hi'
```